# Get the first day name (Mon, Tues...) of the month

Tags: javascript

As the title says I'm trying to get the first day name that a given month starts on.  So for example if Oct 2014 was given the code would return 3 because there are 3 empty blocks before Wed the 1st. Again if I provided Jan 2015, I should get 4. Here is my function:

```
function getDayMonthStartsOn(month, year) {
    var day = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-01").getDay();
    day = (day === 0) ? 7 : day;
    return day;
}
```

My problem is that it seems to work for Jan 2015 but not Oct 2014.

Comment: And what exactly isn't working, and what is the question?

Comment: You...want the `nth` day of the week that is the first day of the given month?

Comment: Seems to return exactly what it says it does -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wd5h9sy6/**

Comment: The above code seems to work fine for some months and not for others.  Seems to work for Jan 2015 but not Oct 2014.  My question is what do I need to do for this code to return the correct number for any given month/year combination.

Comment: But `console.log( getDayMonthStartsOn(10, 2014) ) // 3`, and October 2014 started on a Wednesday (the 3rd day of the week). How does it *not* work?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you really should pass numbers to `new Date` instead of strings ?

Comment: I tried several values and look to work fine

Comment: When i try 10, 2014 I get 2 as a return value

Comment: Use `getUTCDay()` instead of `getDay()`. Your code is still incorrect because it will return the same value for Sunday and Saturday. When it's the October 1st, 2014 in UTC, it seems to still be September 30th in your time zone.

Comment: @FelixKling - That worked. Seems to running fine now.  I'll fix the sat/sun issue. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getUTCDay()` instead of `getDay()`.